# Use Maven proxy settings in custom plugin

Tags: java, maven, proxy

This question is NOT about how to configure the maven proxy settings itself in the settings.xml.

Currently i try to write a maven plugin on my own that assembles/downloads some required files from the web. (No maven repo)
However the plugin might be executed from behind a proxy thats why I would like to use the maven proxy settings in my plugin's code somehow.

However I struggle to get the active proxy settings and configure my downloader accordingly.

Since maven already has a downloader (which uses the proxy settings properly) itself I would like to know how I can get an instance of that downloader and use it.

Here is my current implementation without the proxy stuff of the downloader:

```
try (InputStream fis = url.openStream()) { // This line needs to be proxy aware
    IOUtils.copy(fis, fos);
} catch (final IOException e) {
    throw new MojoExecutionException("Failed to download file", e);
}
```

I'm looking for something like this:

```
InputStream fis = mavenHTTPClient.openStream(url);
```

Comment: are you sure its not available by default?

Comment: The given code example fails with a timeout and I could not find a MavenHTTPClient class anywhere.